# How to turn a list of lists into pairs of points?

Tags: python, list, tuples, coordinates

For example if I have:

```
a = [[[1, 1, 10], [148, 191, 203]], 
     [[133, 100], [19, 34]], 
     [[230, 200], [44, 68]]]
```

I would like to turn "a" it into:

```
[(1,148), (1,191), (10,203), (133,19), (100,34), (230,44), (200,68)]
```

Basically within each inner list I have a list of x values and a list of y values and I would like to pair them together. So `a[0][0][0]` and `a[0][1][0]` would be a pair. Is there a simple way that I would be able to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` to put together each pair of lists into a list of tuples:

```
a = [[[1, 1, 10], [148, 191, 203]], 
     [[133, 100], [19, 34]], 
     [[230, 200], [44, 68]]]

print([z for x, y in a for z in zip(x, y)])
```

Output:

```
[(1, 148), (1, 191), (10, 203), (133, 19), (100, 34), (230, 44), (200, 68)]
```